# Process JavaScript on server

Tags: javascript, asp.net, serverside-javascript

I use third-party JavaScript grid control. The matter is, it renders completely on client side and takes much time for this (creating DOM and corresponding JS objects). It can be normal for PC, but completely bad for mobile browsers like iPad's Safari (for about 1 minute rendering time). I apply many different optimization tricks, but the main problem is grid's rendering time.
So, I wonder, is there any ability to perform rendering of HTML page on server side and return to the client completed page with JS objects?
By another words, I need to launch web page on server side, get the resulted DOM and JS objects and return this to client, like it was performed on client browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, I wonder, is there any ability to perform rendering of HTML page on server side and return to the client completed page with JS objects?

No. You can produce either HTML or JavaScript on server side, but the actual execution of the JavaScript and rendering of the control is not a task you can delegate to the server.

I don't know what is causing the actual performance issue, but you may want to look into paginating your results on server side so the client needs to render only one pageful at a time.

Comment: The control I use is a data grid with great functionality, so, it takes much time to render. Look http://www.tgantt.com/treegrid/www/Gantt.html

Comment: @DotNet yeah, I see what you mean. Pretty cool! But you can't delegate that rendering to the server. It's simply not possible.